# Vue JS load dynamic component in element

Tags: vue.js, components, mount

I have the code below:

```
let templateName = '#' + className + 'Properties';
const vue2 = {
               template: templateName,
               el: "#app2"
             };
var vm = new Vue(vue2).$mount();
```

Everytime, the variable className will have different value, so that template will be different everytime. Now once I mount the component for the first time, it works, but the same template mounts always even if the className is different.

Please guide

Comment: Can you create a minimal a example in CodePen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as below :

```
                    if (null !== vm) {
                        vm.$destroy();
                        vm.$el.remove()
                        vm = null
                    }

                    const vueContainer = document.createElement('div');
                    vueContainer.setAttribute("id", "app9");
                    $("#app2").append(vueContainer);                    

                    let templateName = '#' + className + 'Properties';
                    const vue2 = {
                        template: templateName,
                        el: "#app9"
                    };

                    vm = (new (Vue.extend(vue2))).$mount(vueContainer)
```